# calculate variance using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, variance

I have a financial price time series:

```
date     price   variance_3

1/1/2012  1,1    n/a
2/1/2012  1,2    n/a
3/1/2012  1,3    
4/1/2012  1,3
7/1/2012  1,2
8/1/2012  1.3
```

I intend to calculate the variance for each date using the last 3 prices in time.
Do you see a chance to accomplish this using SQL only?

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  var_pop(price) as variance
from    (
        select  price
        from    YourTable
        order by
                date desc
        limit   3
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Comment: Suggest you use `VAR_POP` (or `VAR_SAMP`, depending on which one is after) instead of `STDDEV` given the OP asked for variance...

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. So basically: in order to fill the column I need to add this SQL to a stored procedure and move through the table updating each row?

Comment: @eggyal: done #caliph: sure, or you could use any client language to do so